# Splitting fields of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $f,g$ $\in$ $F[X]$ non constant polynomials and $K$ a splitting field over $F$.
Suppose that $g|f$ in $F[X]$.Prove that $g$ splits to linear factors of $K[X]$.Is $K$ a splitting field of $g$?

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, let $\alpha$ be a zero of $g$ and $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, for some polynomial $h$ in $F[x]$. Then we have that $g(\alpha) = 0 \implies f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)h(\alpha) = 0$. So as $\alpha$ is a zero of $f$, we have that $\alpha \in K$, so $g$ splits in $K$.

A simple counterexample to the second question is to consider $f(x) = (x-1)(x^2+1)$ and $g(x) = x-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Obviously the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, while the splitting field of $g$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How can we deduce from that, that $g=a(x-u_1)....(x-u_m)$?

Comment: @capo Well we've proven that every zero of $g$ is in $K$, so each of the polynomials $(x-u_i)$ is in $K$. We know that $g$ factors into irreducible factors in $K$, but as every zero is in $K$, the irreducible factors are actually linear factors.

Comment: we apply the same argument if g is irreducible by finding a field that contains roots of g?

Comment: @capo I don't know what you're refering to, but the smallest field that contains the roots of $g$ is the splitting field of $g$. For how to get the splitting field you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field)

Comment: every polynomial with degree>0 has a splitting field,so it is enough to prove that the splitting field of g is a subset of the splitting field of f over F

Comment: @capo Yes. Or in other words that every zero of $g$ is in the splitting field of $F$.